# Probability distribution where a random variable $X$ is doubled with probability $1/2$ and halved with probability $1/2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a random process where at each step a variable $X$ is doubled with probability $1/2$ and halved with probability $1/2$. Initially, $X = 2^k$ (for some $k ≥ 0$), and if $X = 1$ at any point, the process stops.

Let $P_{k,n}$ denote the probability that $X$ equals $2^n$ sometime during this process, given that initially $ X = 2^k $.

(i) Compute $P_{k,n}$ for $k = 0$, $k = n/2$ and $k = n$, where $n$ is a positive even integer.
(ii) Give an expression for $P_{k,n}$ for all $k ≥ 0$.

For the part (i) for $k = 0$, I think since it is already in the final state and $n$ is a positive even integer, the probability of that happening should be zero. But, for the other parts I'm clueless as in how to even proceed in such a question.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009119/681211) answer is useful for finding the expected value but I couldn't get an idea about the probability distribution.

Comment: what can you say about $\log X$?

Comment: I'm sorry not able to imagine. Logically the power should give us an idea about the steps it must've taken at each level. At each level it has two choice either add or subtract 1, somewhat like Bernoulli. But not able to think beyond that.

Comment: $Y = \log_2 X$ is a random walk on integers. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: I wasn't until now. This is really nice!